# nodejs not connecting to spotilocal on windows

Tags: windows, node.js, spotify

i'm trying to connect to spotilocal (http://127.0.0.1:4380/remote/status).
when i'm running my code in mac OS X it works like a charm.
if i run the same code in windows (using a VM) it just doesn't work.
does it have to do with being in a VM?

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotify on Windows doesn't use a network service for this feature, so you won't be able to see it like you can in Mac. However in the new beta client (which you can find a link for on the Spotify community forums) both Windows and Mac behave the same way, so it should work there. So try the beta client out and see if it doesn't work there.

Comment: great. that was it. thank you, worked great. now just have to wait for ARM support :P

Comment: @PedroAfonso Glad to hear it. :) But don't hold your breath for ARM support. Although most of the Spotify core libs are ported to ARM (hence being used in our mobile clients), the desktop client relies on CEF (https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) and I wouldn't count on an ARM port of it anytime soon...